# Create shortcut that runs a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to create a powershell script that creates a shortcut in the windows 7 taskbar, that runs a batch file from cmd.exe.

Trying to do as told in these two posts:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/100249/how-to-pin-either-a-shortcut-or-a-batch-file-to-the-new-windows-7-taskbar
2. [How to create a shortcut using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701840/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-powershell-or-cmd)

Basically I want to set a shortcut files Target property to be something like:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Dev\Batch files\cmake-guiMSVC1064bit.bat"
```

What I got so far in my powershell script is:

```
$batchPath = "C:\Dev\my_batchfile.bat"
$taskbarFolder = "$Home\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\Taskbar\"
$cmdPath = (Get-Command cmd | Select-Object Definition).Definition
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$objShortCut = $objShell.CreateShortcut("$shortcutFolder\$batchName.lnk")

#TODO problem ... :(
$objShortCut.TargetPath = "$cmdPath /C $batchPath"

$objShortCut.Save()
```

This results in the following error:

```
Exception setting "TargetPath": "The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))" At C:\Dev\Powershell\GetTools.ps1:220 char:18
+     $objShortCut. <<<< TargetPath = "$cmdPath /C $batchPath"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: I already have the batch file, just need to make a powershell script that creates a shortcut where the target property is something like: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Dev\Batch files\cmake-guiMSVC1064bit.bat"

Comment: Why not right click on the batch file->create shortcut...?

Comment: Because this is part of a larger script that is supposed to be run on multiple machines with a minimum of human interaction. :)

Comment: Ah, okay. Anyway, where is `$batchPath` defined? Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: Just nissed that variable in the copy/paste, fixed it in the post now, still got the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the arguments via the Arguments property:

```
$batchName = 'cmd'
$batchPath="D:\Temp\New folder\test.bat"
$taskbarFolder = "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\Taskbar\"
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$objShortCut = $objShell.CreateShortcut("$taskbarFolder\$batchName.lnk")
$objShortCut.TargetPath = 'cmd'
$objShortCut.Arguments="/c ""$batchPath"""
$objShortCut.Save()
```