# Powershell webclient dot in Filename

Tags: .net, powershell, webclient

I have a Problem with the .Net webclient object in powershell.

If I'd like to download a file like `https://example.ch/15.01.2015 something.docx` it doesn't work because of the multiple `.` in the filename.

A Problem like this is descripted in [Powershell webclient trailing dot in URL bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823803/powershell-webclient-trailing-dot-in-url-bug#new-answer?newreg=95d9434caffb46888247901e8168af11) but de difference is: there is the `.` in a folder.

I tried the Code from there, but it doesn't work either. My Code is:

```
$source = @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Net;

public class FixedWebClient
{
    public static System.Net.WebClient NewWebClient()
    {
        MethodInfo getSyntax = typeof(UriParser).GetMethod("GetSyntax", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        FieldInfo flagsField = typeof(UriParser).GetField("m_Flags", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (getSyntax != null && flagsField != null)
        {
            foreach (string scheme in new[] { "http", "https" })
            {
                UriParser parser = (UriParser)getSyntax.Invoke(null, new object[] { scheme });
                if (parser != null)
                {
                    int flagsValue = (int)flagsField.GetValue(parser);
                    // Clear the CanonicalizeAsFilePath attribute
                    if ((flagsValue & 0x1000000) != 0){
                        flagsField.SetValue(parser, flagsValue & ~0x1000000);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new System.Net.WebClient();
    }
}
"@

$file = "https://example.ch/15.01.2015 something.docx"
$target = "C:\temp\15.01.2015 something.docx"

#Remove-Typedata 'FixedWebClient'
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source
$client = [FixedWebClient]::NewWebClient()
$client.UseDefaultCredentials=$true

$client.DownloadFile( $file , $target )
```

Does anyone know, how i can solve my Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.
Instead of using the System.Net.WebClient, I download the files with **WebDav**. 
[Pswebdav library](http://code.google.com/p/pswebdav/) is useful.