# Creating desktop icon after installing powershell

Tags: powershell, cygwin

I am using the following code to install cygwin using powershell.

http://www.jbmurphy.com/2011/06/16/powershell-script-to-install-cygwin/
It successfully installs but the only problem is there is no shortcut or "start the program on start is not done". Can it be done?

Comment: Check here: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_create_shortcut.htm. You can start the program from poweshell: "& c:\Cygwin\bin\xxx.exe"

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what cygwin is but if you only want to create a shortcut to a specific program, this should answer your question:

[How to create a shortcut using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701840/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-powershell)