# Deploy IE shotcut from server to multiple PCs

Tags: deployment, psexec, sccm

I'm new to sccm, psexec, and vb scripting. I need help copying a Internet Explorer shortcut from a server to multiple computers.

Lets say my link is named Shortcut.lnk and is located on \troyserver\shortcut.lnk and I need to push it to troypc1, troypc2, troypc3. How could I do this?

Can someone help me out with this? i've tried using xcopy and psexec and I cannot come up with something simple that works.

I need everything spelled out in detail because im a rookie.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this question was asked without searching.  Duplicate of this question [How to create a shortcut using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701840/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-powershell) where the answer is listed out with example code.

You can use Powershell to create a shortcut on a remote computer.  (edit) Also note you can use Powershell's foreach to loop through a list of computers.  There are numerous examples of this available on StackOverFlow.

```
Example:
PS C:\> $shell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
PS C:\> $shell

SpecialFolders                          CurrentDirectory
--------------                          ----------------
System.__ComObject                      C:\


PS C:\> $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut('\\SERVER\c$\mine.lnk')
PS C:\> $shortcut.TargetPath = c:\Windows\Notepad.exe
PS C:\> $shortcut.TargetPath = "c:\Windows\Notepad.exe"
PS C:\> $shortcut.save()
PS C:\> ls '\\itdrenmvp787\c$\mine.lnk'


Directory: \\itdrenmvp787\c$\

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        12/23/2014   3:18 PM        673 mine.lnk
```