# Create " *.url " file using powershell and CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd

i was inquiring if there are options to create a url shortcut to be placed on c:\users\username\favorites to be applied to be added to the login script of the user on Active directory to create the favorites for any user
i tried searching all over the internet and i only found "MD" and "MKDir" commands

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a shortcut using Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701840/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-powershell). Pretty sure it is no different. Just use your URL as the target and add a URL extension.

Answer (score 3):

Not the most PowerShell answer but this is the widely used one with the best compatibility in versions. Much like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701840/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-powershell) but small changes for URLs

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$Home\Favorites\Google.url")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "http://www.google.ca"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

This will make a shortcut to Google in your favorites. `$Home` being one of PowerShell's [Automatic Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx)

If you happen to have PowerShell 5.0 it can now do this natively. Again refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29002672/3829407) for more information