# Use PowerShell to add and remove shortcuts from Explorer's favorite bar

Tags: powershell, windows-7, powershell-2.0, explorer

Is there a way to use PowerShell to manage Explorer's shortcut?

For example, remove `7346` then add a link to `~/Projects/9999`?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Favourites in Explorer are shortcuts in `\Links` folder in your profile. So if you want to remove *7346*:

```
rm $home\Links\7346.lnk
```

Creating one is rather cumbersome in PS:

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$Home\Links\9999.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "$home\9999"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Adjust target path if *9999* doesn't sit in the root of your user profile.

Comment: You should probably use `$env:USERPROFILE` instead of `$Home` (in case AD profile path points to a network share)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701840/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-powershell) had a similar answer.