# Powershell vs GUI shortcuts

Tags: powershell, new-item

I have a file named new.txt. Using GUI I can create a shortcut, for example, "new.lnk". When I click on "new.lnk" file, Notepad is opened with the contents of "new.txt" file. When I create the shortcut using PowerShell

```
NEW-ITEM -TYPE SYMBOLICLINK -TARGET "NEW.TXT" "NEW.LNK"
```

I can see the contents of the file using

```
CAT "NEW.LNK"
```

but the shortcut file is not working in the GUI: it does nothing.

I expect to see the contents in Notepad editor. The properties of the file created using GUI and PowerShell are the same, except for "Start in" information: blank when the short cut is created using PowerShell and with the path file directory when using GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbolic link (symlink) is not the same as Windows shortcut. A symbolic link is created on file system level - it says "here's a file with such filename, but the content is actually in this other file". It's size is 0 Bytes, as it just points to other file. 
It would be more proper to name the file "new-linked.txt" instead of "new.lnk".

A shortcut ".lnk" is a separate file that is interpreted by Windows shell. It contains a path to the target file (among other additional properties). If you create shortcut from UI and then try `cat my.lnk`, you'll see the content of the shortcut file itself, not the target file.

For creating a Windows shortcut from Powershell, see [How to create a shortcut using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701840/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-powershell).