# how to create several shortcuts at the same time for all .exe files in a directory using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, exe, shortcut

Hi I want to create several shortcuts at same time using powershel and something like this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\something\ -Include *.exe -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

get the results and generate shortcuts(.lnk files) for all .exe files

(.exe is just one example of file type)

Can u help me? thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a shortcut using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701840/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create shortcuts of all your `.exe` files in a directory, you can do the following:

- Create *Windows Script host* COM object to create shortcuts. You can have a look at [Creating COM Objects with New-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-.net-and-com-objects--new-object-?view=powershell-7#creating-com-objects-with-new-object) from MSDN for more information.
- Get all `.exe` files in a directory. Similar to what you have done already with [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7).
- Iterate each of these files. Can use [`foreach`](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html) or [`Foreach-Object`](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html) here.
- Extract `BaseName` from files. This means getting `test` from `test.exe`. We need this to make the shortcut file.
- Create shortcut from path. This path is just the destination path + filename + `.lnk` extension. We can use [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7) here to make this path.
- Set target path of shortcut to the executable and save shortcut.

**Demonstration:**

```
$sourcePath = "C:\path\to\shortcuts"
$destinationPath = "C:\path\to\destination"

# Create COM Object for creating shortcuts
$wshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

# Get all .exe files from source directory
$exeFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter *.exe -Recurse

# Go through each file
foreach ($file in $exeFiles)
{
    # Get executable filename
    $basename = $file.BaseName

    # Create shortcut path to save to
    $shortcutPath = Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath ($basename + ".lnk")

    # Create shortcut
    $shortcut = $wshShell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath)

    # Set target path of shortcut to executable
    $shortcut.TargetPath = $file.FullName

    # Finally save the shortcut to the path
    $shortcut.Save()
}
```